# Missing mesh display panel in 2.71

Tags: mesh, interface

I'm new to Blender and currently following a tutorial.  I am using v2.71, the tutorial was filmed on 2.66.1.

On the tutorial in the properties menu there is a tab called "Mesh Display". But on my version this option is not there and I can't find it! So, where is it???

Answer (score 6):

This panel is only available in *edit mode*. Press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to toggle edit mode, or select it from the drop down in the header of the 3D view:

[image]

Once you are in edit mode, you should see the mesh display panel in the *Properties region* (on the right in the above screenshot), which you can toggle visible with <kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply!  I can now advance with my turorial.

Comment: Note that the drop down is not in the header in the 3D view; it is the properties shelf (accessed with the N key) of the 3D window in Edit mode.

Comment: @brasshat By "drop down" I meant the mode selection drop down, which is in the header. I edited to reduce confusion.